# msg can't reach the stat chart for multiple deliveries

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to change the existing model in Anylogic (product delivery) and trying to move trucks to various locations. in manufacturing processes I add batch and hold to put 5 orders in the truck, but after I can't communicate with truck state chart and can't make it read the trigger (msg). I tried various methods but couldn't make it work. I'm new in anylogic and your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you should do is go to the truck agent, to the connections object, and verify if your message is being sent

[image]

Also to understand better how messages work, i suggest you watch the following video which is part of the course available at [noorjax.teachable.com](https://noorjax.teachable.com)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe2U8IAhlHM

Comment: Thanks for your support, I'm evaluating material you shared. Hope I'll find the right solution.

Comment: hello, finally my msg reached truck destination. Now  I have 3 orders batch in shipment and shipment sends msg to trucks. I want to move trucks to the order destinations. I have orderCollection, where my daily orders are stored and variable shipment, located in the agent truck. I want variable shipment to pull data from orderCollection and moveTo destination. My model is very close to product delivery model in anylogic cloud, just add the batch and change the truck statechart to move to different locations. Thanks in advance

Comment: ask a brand new question i suggest

Comment: I did but no reply. I try to do it again thanks anyway

Comment: I followed your suggestion, placed new question and qaiting for reply